# Transform arguments to logical propositions

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have the following arguments that I need to transform to logical propositions and prove if they are true

> Every person that goes to Hawaii walks beneath coconuts
>
> There are persons that, walking beneath coconuts, have their head cracked
>
> Therefore, who goes to Hawaii may have their heads cracked

So I started like this:

> ∀x( (P(x) ^ H(x)) -> W(x))

as the first argument, P means is that x is a person;

H means that x goes to Hawaii;

W is x walks beneath coconuts.

> ∃x( (P(x) -> (W(x) ^ C(x))

as my second argument, with C meaning that x has a cracked head.

But I have no idea how to tranform the last argument in a logical notation. My biggest problem is the "may have their heads cracked", beacuse I don't know how to express possibility in this case. I thought about using v (or) but it didn't feel right. The sorce material I'm using don't have examples like this, and so far I've found nothing similar in forums.

Any tips are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think you are right to have doubts about "how to express possibility" in the conclusion.  The logic of possibility/necessity is a *modal logic*, often expressed in terms of [modal operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) that are analogous to quantifiers.  However it seems this is beyond the material you are studying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second premise, you need $$\exists x( ((P(x) \land W(x)) \land C(x)) $$

For the last (conclusion): "Therefore, who goes to Hawaii may have their heads cracked" you might translate as follows: "For all persons who go to Hawaii, there are some who have their heads cracked."

$$\forall(x) \Big(\big(P(x)\land H(x)\big)\rightarrow \exists(x)\big(C(x)\big)\Big)$$

Comment: I'm assuming you haven't covered modal logic?